# Checking 100 conditions: Stored Procedure or code behind with "if else if" statements?

Tags: stored-procedures, switch-statement, case

I have to check for a value in my website, I need to do this for nearly 100 times
I wrote like this

```
switch(100)
{
    case (1):
       do this
    break;

    case (2):
       do this
    break;

    case (3): do this
```

like this i have to write 100 conditions. I need to assign some values to 4 of my variables in each case block.
Is this fine to write like this? Or should I write some procedure to get this, in that procedure also I have to assign values to 4 of my variables, then it will be lengthy mostly.

So, which is better performance wise?

Comment: do you really have hundred cases? your code smells?

Comment: if it's just simple assignments based on an input value, try a lookup map (which can also be an array).

Comment: I assume you mean a database stored procedure? Why use a stored procedure? You're not even storing anything in a database so why connect to it?

Comment: Are we talking about mysql? are you asking if it's better to do it in the application (PHP)? ...?

Comment: It s about ms sql. I dont have 100 cases but I have 60 to 70 cases, so I am asking which will give best performance.What is a lookupmap? How can I use array for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I created a table in DB, placed those 4 variables as columns filled that columns with the data corresponding to my Input value. Created a stored proc to retrieve the values passing the input value.

Thanks to every one who suggested